# TimeLine в виде кадров из mediaelementa

Tags: c#, uwp, видео

На скрине ниже есть таймлайн в виде кадров, как сделать такой же? 
Любые идеи.
Само приложение называется Effects Videos – Filters for Videos из винстора и судя по всему приложению это сделать не так уж и сложно.

[image: TimeLine]

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать использовать [порт библиотеки ffmpeg для UWP](https://github.com/Microsoft/FFmpegInterop) (есть еще и [версия](https://github.com/jessejiang0214/FFmpeg) от другого разработчика). У ffmpeg есть опция создания отдельных кадров (в стандартных форматах изображений) из видео, по заданному времени, пример командной строки:

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.avi -vf fps=1/60 img%03d.jpg
```

Естественно, что нужно использовать соответствующие вызовы собранной библиотеки, а не командную строку.

Comment: Да, еще одна "идея в копилку" (думаю, что реализуемо на 99%): для Windows 10 UWP можно использовать [custom video effect](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/custom-video-effects), пример есть на [github](https://github.com/r2d2rigo/UWP-Samples/tree/b05d49bca87915bd9725361b4211aebf7c21c490/CustomVideoEffect).

Функция ProcessFrame дает доступ к содержимому фрейма:

`public void ProcessFrame(ProcessVideoFrameContext context)
{
    var softBmp = context.InputFrame.SoftwareBitmap;
}`